# "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream" every 13 hours 14 minutes

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-recording

I have a problem with the latest ffmpeg from zeranoe.
Every 13h14m ffmpeg stops recording.

```
ffmpeg started on 2017-09-28 at 10:36:49
Report written to "ffmpeg-20170928-103649.log"
Command line:
"D:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe" -report
ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

I record video streams from 3 cameras.

Stream 1:

```
Input #0, rtp, from 'rtp://225.1.1.1:1024':
  Duration: N/A, start: 60424.501000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressiv
e), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, mono,
fltp, 164 kb/s
```

Streams 2,3:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.3.36:554/stream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed by "Pelco Streaming Server"
    comment         : stream1
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.219167, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, 25 fps,
25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I record each of them with segmentation every 1 minute using separated ffmpeg instances like:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://192.168.3.36:554/stream1" -vcodec copy -an -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60 "novus-%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.ts"
```

Every 13 hours 14 minutes (from beginning of recording) each ffmpeg stops recording with messages like "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0". And it doesn't matter when I started every ffmpeg intance: if I started instance №2 1 minute later that instance №1, it will stop recording in 1 minute after №1 accordingly. I tried it on two PC: Windows Server 2012 x64 and Windows 10 x64.

```
...
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 408 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] stream:0 start_pts_time:47640.5 pts:4289549528 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289549528 dts_time:47661.7 -> pts:4289549528 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289549528 dts_time:47661.7
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 408 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] stream:0 start_pts_time:47640.5 pts:4289553131 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289553131 dts_time:47661.7 -> pts:4289553131 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289553131 dts_time:47661.7
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 408 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] stream:0 start_pts_time:47640.5 pts:4289556734 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556734 dts_time:47661.7 -> pts:4289556734 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556734 dts_time:47661.7
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 336 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 4289535114, current: -5428580; changing to 4289535115. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 000000000034e780] stream:0 start_pts_time:47640.5 pts:4289556735 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556735 dts_time:47661.7 -> pts:4289556735 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556735 dts_time:47661.7
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 408 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 4289535115, current: -5424977; changing to 4289535116. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 000000000034e780] stream:0 start_pts_time:47640.5 pts:4289556736 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556736 dts_time:47661.7 -> pts:4289556736 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556736 dts_time:47661.7
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 408 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 4289535116, current: -5421374; changing to 4289535117. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 000000000034e780] stream:0 start_pts_time:47640.5 pts:4289556737 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556737 dts_time:47661.7 -> pts:4289556737 pts_time:47661.7 dts:4289556737 dts_time:47661.7
frame=1190370 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=13:14:21.50 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x    
[NULL @ 000000000034a900] SEI type 5 size 408 truncated at 160
[segment @ 000000000034e780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 4289535117, current: -5417772; changing to 4289535118. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
...
```

The full debug log with this problem is here (25 Mb, zipped):
​https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1LIS8G55R7-OGY4QkdkQ0J1cVE/view?usp=sharing
I can't record video infinitely. Every 13 hours I have broken recording. I tried to record with "copytb 1", "genpts" but it doesn't help. I don't think it is the network problem, because I tried to record the same rtsp stream by two instances of ffmpeg with time shift of start: they stuck separately at separate time.
Does anyone know how to solve it? I can provide you with another information you need about this.

Update: If I wait 13 hours after bug appeared, the recording starts again.

Answer (score 5):

With certain IP cameras, we become aware of this issue as well, and found a fix:

-correct_ts_overflow 0

Explaination: It stems from a couple of issues in FFMPEG. First, timestamps are generated out of the RTP demuxer. When there is more than one stream for the camera, timestamps are generated using the RTCP ntp time and RTP timestamps together for proper stream timing. However, for only one stream, a cumulative timestamp is generated from the the RTP timestamp. The problem lies in that some cameras report a starting timestamp in the SDP that is greater than the first RTP packet timestamp which is used as a base timestamp. This in turn creates a negative timestamp passed to ff_read_frame. The other issue is that RTSP/RTP sets its timestamp wrap bits as 32 bits. The problem is that the timestamps in the case of a single stream are really an int 64 bit timestamp, since the timestamps are not absolute timestamps, but rather a cumulative timestamps. This timestamp won't wrap until bits 63 for positive timestamps.

What we found however is that inside the call to ff_read_frame there is some logic to deal with PTS/DTS wrapping used for seeking during rollover situations. Because the the first timestamp in this case is negative AND the wrap bits are set to 32 bits, the wrap code gets setup incorrectly. So, with cameras that start with a negative timestamp, the wrap code subtracts UINT32MAX from a timestamp when it becomes a value greater than some indexed value (I believe roughly 60 seconds of video before UINT32MAX). This then generates a new negative timestamp out of ff_read_frame. Since ffmpeg.c then detects this as a non-monotonic timestamp, the new output timestamp is just one tick greater than the old messing up the entire output stream. It then takes another UINT32MAX for the timestamps from the RTP demuxer to catch back up, or roughly 13 hours.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a 32 bit unsigned integer overflow.
The max value for a 32 bit unsigned integer is 4294967295 which is close to your timestamps.

Now the question is: Is it ffmpeg or your RTP source?
You have to isolate the problem. Use live555's sample code and record your stream without ffmpeg and log the timestamps.

If I take a wild guess - I'd say its probably your network source that has a buggy RTP (RTCP) implementation.

Comment: I found that this problem doesn't occur if I write to ".h264" file, not to ".ts".
Also I tried the sample from live555 - it writes to raw h264 file without problems. Sorry, but I didn't found how to log timestamps with live555 sample.

Comment: This is a step forward - I'd say ffmpeg's MPEG-2 Transport Stream muxer overflows a 32 bit variable - possible in a calculation.